# Warum ist dieser Satz im Passiv?

Tags: passive

Ich habe nun einen Satz gelesen:

> Während der Bus fährt, darf nicht mit dem Fahrer gesprochen werden.

Der Satz verwirrt mich sehr. Warum gibt es kein "man" in dem Satz? Und warum ist dieser Satz im Passiv? Ich denke, dass dieser Satz wie

> Während der Bus fährt, darf man nicht mit dem Fahrer sprechen.

sein soll. Könnten Sie mir bitte helfen? Tausend Dank!

Comment: Ich habe mir erlaubt, die Umlaute zu korrigieren.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Ob das Passiv verwendet wird, oder ob man das Passiv nicht verwendet, ist eine reine Stilfrage. Wie im vorherigen Satz gezeigt.

Comment: Das ist doch das Schöne an Sprachen, dass es meist mehr als eine Möglichkeit gibt, etwas auszudrücken.

Comment: @RHa Müsste man nicht vielmehr sagen, dass es *immer* mehrere Möglichkeiten gibt, etwas auszudrücken? Jedenfalls fällt mir kein Fall ein, wo es nur *eine* gäbe.